# non-relationship state of an entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was studying Entity Listeners in Jpa. In says - "In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked."

I am not able to understand meaning of "non-relationship state of the entity" line. Please anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It means you cannot alter the entity's information that refers to another entity, i.e. it's relationship.

Non-relationship state refers to persistent fields/properties that do not involve or define relationships with other entities.